# no video with supported format and MIME type found. What does this mean and how can I change this

Tags: html, firefox, mime-types, mime

no video with supported format and MIME type found

A huge screen for video is displayed and says the message above. How do I solve this?
This happens to me only in Mozilla Fire fox and not on Google Chrome. I am using webm videos and mp4 videos.

This is for html5 video.

Comment: I have exactly the same. Started happening when Firefox 12 came out.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The webserver might not be sending the correct MIME types. Depending on the server you may be able to add a .htaccess file with the following:

```
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```

If that doesn't work try searching for "server mime types".

Comment: This got video working, but no audio.  I had to do this: Add type video/ogg .ogv
Add type audio/ogg .oga

Comment: Where do you add the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 9):

Go to IIS Manager. Click MIME Types Under IIS. Click Add Button. Enter the following Details.

File Name Extension: .webm
MIME Type: video/webm

Again Add,
File Name Extension: .ogv
MIME Type: video/ogg

And
File Name Extension: .mp4
MIME Type: video/mp4

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="ho.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="ho.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video> 
</body>
</html>
```

this code worked fine for me...Found it from w3schools.com...Incase you still have issues try to add the mime types in the iis manager

Answer (score -4):

I have the same problem and this is how I fix it:
Open: "C:\Users\DuongKiet\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config" --> where "C:\Users\DuongKiet\" depends on your folder name.

Edit applicationhost.config, go to this line:

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".mp3" mimeType="audio/mpeg" />
```

then insert this line below:

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" /> --> problemo solved
```

In case you cannot locate the folder, just follow this link for instruction how to add a new mime type:
http://www.misfitgeek.com/use-html5-video-tags-in-your-asp-net-applications/