# How to solve playing video issue in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, video, repeater

Helli Guys!

I have a issue with playing video based on path of video on run time in web video player. there is a ASP code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<video src='<%# GetVideoPlayUrl(Eval("id")) %>' width="900" height="400" 
 controls="" preload=""></video>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I have a video Path in database that is saved in db like this `~\StoreVideo\VQOFY.mp4`

```
protected string GetVideoPlayUrl(object Id)
{
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Id);
        string ret = "";
        ret = "" + VideoUploads.GetVideoPath(id) + "";
        return ret; I'm return value `~\StoreVideo\VQOFY.mp4`
}
```

The video is not uploading in player i also tried this

```
protected string GetVideoPlayUrl(object Id)
{
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Id);
        string ret = "";
        ret = "" + VideoUploads.GetVideoPath(id).Replace("~\\","").Replace("\\","/") + "";
        return ret; I'm return value `StoreVideo/VQOFY.mp4`
}
```

still not working i dont know where was im doing wrong I really need a help in this issue. to know what is the mistake I'm doing here. please correct me with my code where was a mistake.hope some buddy have a solution for me with it.

Thank you

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424729/no-video-with-supported-format-and-mime-type-found-what-does-this-mean-and-how

Comment: i try that not working please have a look on my code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLs that start with ~/ should be 'resolved' before you use them client-side (the `<video>` element is a client-side HTML element, it is unaware of ASP.NET on the server). Try the following code inside the `src` attribute:

```
<%# ResolveUrl(GetVideoPlayUrl(Eval("id"))) %>
```

If you are returning `"~/videos/some-video.mp4"` from the `GetVideoPlayUrl(id)` method, then the call to `ResolveUrl()` will 'translate' that, maybe to `"../../videos/some-video.mp4"` or maybe to `"videos/some-video.mp4"`. It all depends on where the current page is located relative to the location of the file.

You should check in the final HTML that the (relative) path from the ASPX page to the video file is now correct.

Comment: Hello Michielvo i try this but still same issue and one thing it coming issue with Repeater using i check with the manually add in video tag src='StoreVideo/3SS6G.mp4' that is working but when im using the Repeater and then video didnt able to upload. I dont know what to do now.

Comment: Thank You so much Michielvo it really help full to me for solve the issue now ever thing is working fine =)