# FireFox 31 doesn't play video from Visual Basic 2013 ASP.NET Web Application project

Tags: asp.net, html, firefox, video

My ASP.NET project has a default.aspx page with a  tag to show video.
After publish to remote Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit site, video works at my local desktop Windows-7 Pro when browsing to remote site using IE, Chrome, Safari, but not FireFox 31.

However, FireFox does play it when I debug project locally on desktop at URL:  `http://localhost:54802/default`

```
<video width="640"  controls="controls" preload="auto">
        <source src="APPLICANT_VIDEO/<% = job_video_filename %>.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="APPLICANT_VIDEO/<% = job_video_filename %>.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>   
    <source src="APPLICANT_VIDEO/<% = job_video_filename %>.webm" type="video/webm"/>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: What MIME type is the video file being sent with from the server?  Check in the console.

Comment: .mp4 .ogv and .webm made from VLC

Comment: Those aren't MIME types.

Comment: How can I find out the MIME type?  Check what console?

Comment: Check the network requests in the browser console

Comment: I found the solution here:
[solution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424729/no-video-with-supported-format-and-mime-type-found-what-does-this-mean-and-how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Solution: On my Windows 2008 server > IIS > MIME type >
```

AddType video/webm .webm 
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 
Add type video/ogg .ogv 
Add type audio/ogg .oga