# PHP- Retrive video from Database Mysql

Tags: php, html

This my code for retrieving video from database, while uploading i have copied the video to htdocs folder of mysql and stored the path to the database, while i try to retrieve the video it say an error [mime type not matched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kguA1.png),this is my database [it has only two column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES0wJ.png), [this is my htdocs folder contains of video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcoKG.png)

code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="demo1";
$conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

extract($_POST);

$target_dir = "uploads/";

$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if($upd)
{
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($imageFileType != "mp4" && $imageFileType != "avi" && $imageFileType != "mov" && $imageFileType != "3gp" && $imageFileType != "mpeg")
{
    echo "File Format Not Suppoted";
}

else
{

$video_path=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO video (path) VALUES('$video_path')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$target_file);

echo "uploaded ";


}

}

//display all uploaded video

if($_POST['disp'])

{
  //  echo "came in";

$query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from video");

    while($all_video=mysqli_fetch_array($query))

    {
//echo "test_upload/uploads/".$all_video['path'];

?>


<h1>test_upload/uploads/<?php echo $all_video['path']; ?></h1>
   <video width="300" height="200" controls>
     <source src="test_upload/uploads/<?php echo $all_video['path']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>



    <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no video with supported format and MIME type found. What does this mean and how can I change this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424729/no-video-with-supported-format-and-mime-type-found-what-does-this-mean-and-how)

Comment: you're  statically setting the mime type as type="video/mp4" but are looking for mp4, avi or mov files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to try to debug your code. Like try to add php generated  tag and try to open it in new tab.

```
<a href="test_upload/uploads/raj.mp4" >test link put in `raj.php` file</a>
```

I believe you forgot to add starting / so try this link

```
/test_upload/uploads/raj.mp4
```

Or use this link:

```
uploads/raj.mp4
```

I think in your case its just pathing.